# How to exclude specific string using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, substring

I'd like to match strings like:

```
45 meters?
45, meters?
45?
45 ?
```

but not strings like:

```
45 meters you?
45 you  ?
45, and you?
```

In both cases the question mark must be at the end. So, essentially I want to exclude all those strings containing the word "you".

I've tried the following regex:

```
'\d+.*(?!you)\?$'
```

but it matches the second case (probably because of `.*`)

Comment: Can `you` occur anywhere in the string, or only at the end?

Comment: It could be anywhere, but for now I'm interested when it occurs at the end, thank you.

Comment: I meant "anywhere" in the sense that between `you` and `?` there could be some white spaces.

Comment: You could try `\d+.*?(?<!you\?)$`, but it will also match `45 you  ?`. You can't do `(?<!you\s*\?)` because lookbehinds (in most flavors) need to be fixed-length.

Comment: Is regex mandatory? you can make it like: `"you" in mystring`

Comment: The simplest solution is to do 2 passes. On the first pass, keep all of the lines which match a certain expression, on the second pass, filter out all the ones that contain "you".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try this regex to match all the lines which doesn't have the string `you` with `?` at the last,

```
^(?!.*you).*\?$
```

**Explanation:**

A negative lookahead is used in this regex. What it does actually means, it checks for the lines which contains a string `you`. It matches all the lines except the line containing the string `you`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bO7xA8)

Comment: The OP only wants it to discard the match if the word is `you`.

Comment: Sorry, but I need `.`, because it should even match `45, meters?`

Comment: did you want this `^[\d,]+ ?(\w+)?\?$`?

Comment: Better, but again, as @AmalMurali said, it fails `42 test meters?`

Comment: Yes, I think the second one is the best one, but I'll change it in `^(?!.*you).*\?$'` because as I wrote, I also need the question mark at the end of the string. Thank you!!!

Comment: Again, I've changed it to: `^\d+(?!.*you).*\?$` because I need a number at the beginning of the string! :)

Answer (score 15):

There's a [neat trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) to exclude some matches from a regex, which you can use here:

```
>>> import re
>>> corpus = """
... 45 meters?
... 45?
... 45 ?
... 45 meters you?
... 45 you  ?
... 45, and you?
... """
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\d+[^?]*you|(\d+[^?]*\?)")
>>> re.findall(pattern, corpus)
['45 meters?', '45?', '45 ?', '', '', '']
```

The downside is that you get empty matches when the exclusion kicks in, but those are easily filtered out:

```
>>> filter(None, re.findall(pattern, corpus))
['45 meters?', '45?', '45 ?']
```

**How it works:**

The trick is that we only pay attention to captured groups ... so the left hand side of the alternation - `\d+[^?]*you` (or "digits followed by non-?-characters followed by 'you'") matches what you *don't* want, and then we forget about it. Only if the left hand side doesn't match is the right hand side - `(\d+[^?]*\?)` (or "digits followed by non-?-characters followed by '?') - matched, and that one is captured.

Comment: +1. I was writing an answer with the same method, but you were faster.

Comment: Thanks! Negative lookahead is perhaps the better answer to the OP question, but this answer is the answer to my particular question. I've had a hard time finding it due to the sheer profusion of questions all answered by negative lookahead.