# Ignore words containing substring using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am a beginner and have spent considerable amount of time on this. I was partially able to solve it.

**Problem**: I want to ignore all words that have either `the` or `The`. E.g. `atheist, others, The, the` will be excluded. However, `hottie` shouldn't be included because `the` doesn't occur inside the word as a whole word.

I am using Python's `re` engine.

Here's my regex:

```
\b               - Start at word boundary
(?!              - Negative lookahead to avoid starting with the or The
   [t|T]he       - the and The
)
\w+              - Other letters are fine
(?<!             - Negative look behind
    [t|T]he      - the or The shouldn't occur before \w+
)
\b               - Word boundary
```

**Expected output for a given input:**

`Input: Atheist Others Their Hello the The bathe hottie tahaie theater`

`Expected Output: Hello hottie tahaie`

As one can see in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KVHWQ0/1/), I am able to exclude most of the words except words like `atheist`--i.e. cases when `the or The` appear inside words. I searched for this on SO and found some threads such as [How to exclude specific string using regex in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311832/how-to-exclude-specific-string-using-regex-in-python), but they don't seem to be directly related to what I am trying to do.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Please note that I am interested in solving this problem only using regex. I am not looking for solutions using python's string manipulation.

Comment: \w*[t|T]he\w*  would work

Comment: You don't need the `|` in `[t|T]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is simpler than your original regular expression:

```
\b(?!\w*[t|T]he)\w+\b
```

We match a word, but make sure that there is no `the` within the word using a "padded" negative lookahead. Your original approach only disallowed `the` at the front or the back of the word as it allowed for no padding after/before the word boundary.

`(?![tT]he)` only matches *at the current position*, while `(?:\w*[tT]he)` allows the match to extend from the current position, because the `\w*` can be used as filler.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining this a bit? I am having hard time understanding your logic. Specifically, why do you have negative lookahead for `\w*` with `tThe`? I didn't get this part. Also, why is it that words that end in `the` (e.g. bathe) are ignored?

Comment: I use the \w* to allow the RE engine look forward an arbitrary amount of characters into the word. That way, it checks the whole word for `the`, and if it finds it, it fails the whole match.

Comment: Thanks Corion. This is very helpful. It seems `?!\w*[tT]he` would search for `the` and `The` anywhere in a word. I am curious: what's the difference between `?!\w*[tT]he` and `?![tT]he`? I tried this on regex101 and was not sure about the highlights it threw at me. Could you please explain this, if you don't mind?

Comment: `(?![tT]he)` only matches _at the current position_, while `(?:\w*[tT]he)` allows the match to extend from the current position, because the `\w*` can be used as filler.